# Selenium WebDriver/Ruby send_keys character limitations

Tags: ruby, textarea, selenium-webdriver

I'm using Selenium WebDriver on Ruby 1.8.7 on an Ubuntu 12.04 desktop. I have a script that dumps the contents (as a string) of a bunch of data files one file at a time into a form. The data files range in size from 44kB to 92kB. I can manually copy and paste the contents  into the textarea without error. However, when I use my Ruby script with send_keys on the element the script stalls, fails, and never reports an error.

I know I have the correct element and that send_keys in general works because I've sent 'hello world' to the textarea. I also know I'm grabbing the input file correctly because I can break it up line by line and send entire contents of the file to the textarea one line at a time without error.

The line by line send_keys is doable but fairly slow. I'm assuming that the issue is some form of send_keys limitation on the number of bytes/chars/etc. and that my input files have exceeded that limitation. However, my Google searches have turned up nothing in this regard.

Does anyone know what the limitation here is (send_keys or otherwise)? Ideally if it were a send_keys limitation of 1000 chars I would break the input file up 1000 chars at a time and loop thru until the entire file was sent using send_keys. (And that would certainly be faster than sending it 1 line at a time.) Is there an alternative to send_keys, that I'm unaware of, that can send a string of this size?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use the [clipboard gem](http://rubygems.org/gems/clipboard) and then just use the keyboard shortcut to paste on this element.

```
Clipboard.copy(data)
$driver.find_element(:id, "elementFoo").send_keys [:control, 'v']
```

Comment: Initially I was resistant to adding another gem just for this. However, in this case I'm glad you mentioned the gem because I've been wondering how to get access to clipboard and this just answered that as well. Thanks

Comment: Note: for this to work on Ubuntu you need to make sure xclip is installed otherwise it will revert to using a File based clipboard which will not work
    `sudo apt-get install xclip`